# Unable to query table on oracle schema

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the schema HR and USER A and ran the following query

```
**select count(*) from emp_table**
```

Upon running this query no data was returned but the table has data but if i run the query like this

```
**select count(*) from hr.emp_table**
```

then the data is returned.

Thanks

Comment: Either your first query returned an error that you didn't catch.  Or, you have multiple `emp_tables` hanging around, and you need to be explicit about using the one in `hr`.

Comment: The table is the only one of its kind in the schema....

Comment: create or replace public synonym EMP_TABLE for HR.EMP_TABLE

Comment: `Desc hr.emp_table` and `desc emp_table` must be different and also if you can search `all_objects` for `EMP_TABLE` then it will give you hint what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check from which `database` you connected..may be you are connected to wrong `database` table which doesnt has any data..

As you mentioned the below query clearly suggest that you have table `emp_table` in `hr` database which has data:

```
select count(*) from hr.emp_table
```

To verify which database you are connected use below query :

```
select name from v$database;
```

OR

```
SELECT username, machine, program
FROM v$session
WHERE type = 'USER';
```

Comment: I only am connected to one database

Comment: edited answer run this query and let me know what output is showing.....select name from v$database;

Comment: It brought back the SID of the connection to the db

Comment: SELECT username, machine, program
FROM v$session
WHERE type = 'USER';         what does this query return and is it fine is you create synonym on this table..

Comment: USER_A   DESKTOP-V9VBI18 SQL Developer

Comment: select count(*) from USER_A.emp_table..........what does this query return ?...it means you are connected to USER_A database and the emp_table doesnt have data in this database...and when you query select count(*) from hr.emp_table it returns value because this schema user table had data

Answer (score -1):

As your first SQL did not throw any error,Your current schema (Not HR) has emp_table table having no data.
When you use HR.emp_table, it is refereeing your emp_table of HR schema.

So it is always good to prefix **schema** name with table name.

Comment: True but if i am only on this one connection and i try to query without the schema name then it should return the data